why does it output this to me in the console: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
when I try to play a video using the button, I get the error Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input I can't figure out what the reason might be because I'm still new to JavaScript here's my JS code :
let GettedVideo
const Video_player = document.getElementById('vidplay');

 $(window).on('load', function(){
    var fileExt = ".mp4";
 
         $(document).ready(function(){
 
             $.ajax({
                 //This will retrieve the contents of the folder if the folder is configured as 'browsable'
                 url: 'content/videos',
                 success: function (data) {
                     console.log(data);
                    $("#fileNames").html('<ul>');
                    //List all xml file names in the page
 
                     //var filename = this.href.replace(window.location, "").replace("http:///", "");
                    //$("#fileNames").append( '<li>'+filename+'</li>');
 
                     $(data).find("a:contains(" + fileExt + ")").each(function () {
                        var sa = '"PlayVideo("'+ $(this).text() + '")"';
                        console.log(sa)
                         $("#fileNames").append( '<div class="inDiv"<li>'+$(this).text()+ ' '+' </li><button onclick='+ sa +'><i class="fa-solid fa-play"></i> Play</button></div>');
                         GettedVideo = $(this).text()
                         console.log(GettedVideo)
                     });
                     $("#fileNames").append('</ul>');
                 }
             });
 
         });
 });

function PlayVideo(targetVideoName) {
    var videoPath = "content/videos/" + targetVideoName;
    console.log(videoPath);
    Video_player.src = videoPath;
    Video_player.load();
    Video_player.play();
    console.log('Video '+ videoPath + ' Playing...');
};
 

Here my HTML:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>kd</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/style/style.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/icons/fontawesome-free-6.6.0-web/css/fontawesome.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/icons/fontawesome-free-6.6.0-web/css/fontawesome.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/icons/fontawesome-free-6.6.0-web/css/all.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/icons/fontawesome-free-6.6.0-web/css/all.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        
        <div class="elementsBackround">
        <div class="videoDiv"><video controls class="vidCon" id="vidplay">
            <source id="source" src="">
        </video></div>
        
        <h1>Video List:</h1>
        <div class="divElements" id='fileNames'></div>
        </div>
        <script src=" https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/scripts/VideoGet.js" type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[ </script>
    </body>
</html>

I want to make the video play in mp4 by clicking the buttons from the list, but the error is Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input please help me solve this problem
I also can't figure out which line this error occurs on because the line of code is not specified in the error
I tried to look for a solution to this problem on stack overflow but I did not find a solution to my problem

and I tried to solve this problem by placing: " ; " but it didn't help. I also tried to move '"playVideo("'+$(this).text() +'")"'; to var but it didn't help either. in general, I do not know how to solve this problem please help me to solve this problem
here's what it looks like in VS code:
Click Here

The code seems fine, although quite messy. However, the HTML is missing, which means we cannot hope to reproduce your problem. Should I just make up the HTML and hope for the best? Please see: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example.

Sorry, I forgot to add the HTML code. I will now add the HTML code to my question

I fixed it by putting the quotes correctly
New code JavaScript :
let GettedVideo
const Video_player = document.getElementById('vidplay');

$(window).on('load', function(){
   var fileExt = ".mp4";

        $(document).ready(function(){

            $.ajax({
                //This will retrieve the contents of the folder if the folder is configured as 'browsable'
                url: 'content/videos',
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                   $("#fileNames").html('<ul>');
                   //List all xml file names in the page

                    //var filename = this.href.replace(window.location, "").replace("http:///", "");
                   //$("#fileNames").append( '<li>'+filename+'</li>');

                    $(data).find("a:contains(" + fileExt + ")").each(function () {
                       var sa = 'PlayVideo("'+ $(this).text() + '")';
                       console.log(sa)
                        $("#fileNames").append( '<div class="inDiv"<li>'+$(this).text()+ ' '+' </li><button onclick='+ sa +'><i class="fa-solid fa-play"></i> Play</button></div>');
                        GettedVideo = $(this).text()
                        console.log(GettedVideo)
                    });
                    $("#fileNames").append('</ul>');
                }
            });

        });
});

function PlayVideo(targetVideoName) {
   var videoPath = "content/videos/" + targetVideoName;
   console.log(videoPath);
   Video_player.src = videoPath;
   Video_player.load();
   Video_player.play();
   console.log('Video '+ videoPath + ' Playing...');
};

